# CSS/JavaScript: issue when styling canvas (for mouse drawing)

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have this simple code for drawing with mouse in canvas. But if I try to style the canvas, like altering the width or centering, the pointer and line drawn get separated. How do I solve this?

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
};
el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
```

HTML:

CSS:

```
canvas { 
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/icenine/kvwxecez/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEVER** set canvas's width / height using css. It's really a bad idea. Always use the native width / height property of the canvas.

Also, you should probably be using `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` to get the x and y coordinates of the mouse.

Here's a [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3s14wrmp/1/)